# Replace a line by the content of another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a problem. I would like replace a line of a file by the content of another file.

In my first file I have this line: `"#Content"` and I would like to replace that with the content of the file `content.xml`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This can work:

```
your_new_text=$(cat content.xml | sed 's/[^-A-Za-z0-9_]/\\&/g')
sed -i "s/#Content/$your_new_text/" your_file
```

It puts the text from `content.xml` in the variable `$your_new_text`. Then sed does the work: `-i` stands for replacing in the file, looks for `#Content` and replaces by text inside `$your_new_text`.

Note that it has to be wrapped with `"` to work.

Comment: I have the error `sed: 1: "minimize": invalid command code m`. I run under osx

Comment: From what I see in your answer (it should be in your question, though), the problem is that your content.xml file has some protected characters. Using http://stackoverflow.com/a/5329148/1983854 info, we can `cat content.xml | sed 's/[^-A-Za-z0-9_]/\\&/g'` to escape them.

Comment: Thank you, but the "newline" is not escape. I have this error : `unescaped newline inside substitute pattern`. I test that `new=$(cat $file | sed 's/[^-A-Za-z0-9_]/\\&/g' | sed 's/\n/\\&/g')` but it fails.

Answer (score 1):

This can work too, not very effective - but not sensitive to content.

```
cat <(sed '/#Content/,$d' < FILE ) content.xml <(sed '1,/#Content/d' < FILE) > NEWFILE
```

so, catenate

- the first part of FILE (up to #Content - (not included))
- the file `content.xml
- the second part of file (from to #Content - (not included))