# Removing duplicate entries from files on the basis of substring postfixes

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say that I have the following text in a file:

```
foo.bar.baz
bar.baz
123.foo.bar.baz
pqr.abc.def
xyz.abc.def
abc.def.ghi.jkl
def.ghi.jkl
```

How would I remove duplicates from the file, on the basis of postfixes? The expected output without duplicates would be:

```
bar.baz
pqr.abc.def
xyz.abc.def
def.ghi.jkl
```

(Consider `foo.bar.baz` and `bar.baz`. The latter is a substring postfix so only `bar.baz` remains. However, neither of `pqr.abc.def` and `xyz.abc.def` are not substring postfixes of each other, so both remain.)

Comment: Could you be more precise? I don't get the pattern here.

Comment: @dstronczak, I've tried to explain it a bit better, maybe this would make sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_FILE="$1"

in="$(cat $INPUT_FILE)"
out="$in"

for line in $in; do
  out=$(echo "$out" | grep -v "\.$line\$")
done

echo "$out"
```

You need to save it to a script (e.g. `bashor.sh`), make it executable (`chmod +x bashor.sh`) and call it with your input file as the first argument:

```
./bashor.sh path/to/input.txt
```

Comment: I came up with a similar solution. you have one bug though: grep will interpret `.` as any character, so you have to escape it: both the naked `.` and the dots in `$line` (that is, assuming there are no other special characters, and prefixes are always delimited with dot)

Comment: Actually, my solution will be fine if there are only three-character tokens (I intentionally used the `.` a a wildcard). But of course that was a wild assumption, so I escaped the `.` in questions...

Comment: yes, that's a wild assumption. if not, `a.a` will match `aaa`. I'm more worried about that escaping...

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` to escape the string for regular expressions, prefix `.`, postfix `$` and pipe this into GNU grep (`-f -` doesn't work with BSD grep, eg. on a mac).

```
sed 's/[^-A-Za-z0-9_]/\\&/g; s/^/./; s/$/$/' test.txt |grep -vf - test.txt
```

I just used to [regular expression escaping from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329148/695343) and didn't think about whether it is reasonable. On first sight it seems fine, but escapes too much, though probably this is not an issue.